# Xcode: setting version in build script

Tags: xcode, build, plist, bundle

I am trying to set up an automated version number for releases using a script.

My very first build phase (after Target Dependencies) is a Run Script using this script:

```
if [ "${CONFIGURATION}" = "Release" ]; then
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion `date +%Y%m%d%H%M`" ProtoMemory/ProtoMemory-Info.plist
fi
```

Or in plain english: if this is a release build, set the build version to the release date and time.

The script does exactly what I want it to do, but it seems it does it AFTER it's copied the `Info.plist` file to the bundle. Which means I end up with the right build number in my source, but not in my bundle.

Right now, I'm using a stupid workaround where I build it once before I make an archive (effectively building it twice). Is there no way to call a build script before copying the `Info.plist` file? Or is Xcode using some kind of cached version of the plist? Or perhaps I could add a final build phase that copies the `Info.plist` file to the bundle AGAIN...

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use `agvtool`?

`` agvtool new-version -all `date +%Y%m%d%H%M` ``

Comment: Could you explain your solution?

Comment: Check https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/agvtool.1.html